# R ggplot2 error: stacking not well defined when ymin!=0

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have been running this R script for a long time and it always worked perfectly but today I loaded it on a new coworkers computer and noticed my graphs were coming out differently.  On a hunch I reinstalled ggplot2 on my machine and now my plots are the same as my coworker's.

The script takes a dataset that looks like this:

```
    Var1    Var2    value   Var3
1   A   Total   -20.3681969 Total
2   B   Total   -7.8687517  Total
3   C   Total   -5.5482684  Total
4   D   Total   -5.380664   Total
5   E   Total   -1.6060702  Total
6   F   Total   -1.5844055  Total
7   G   Total   -1.571284   Total
8   H   Total   -0.2576642  Total
9   I   Total   -0.2448856  Total
10  J   Total   -0.2114562  Total
11  K   Total   -26.2567781 Total
12  L   Total   -18.3848686 Total
13  A   Ghost   0   Ghost
14  B   Ghost   -20.3681969 Ghost
15  C   Ghost   -28.2369485 Ghost
16  D   Ghost   -33.7852169 Ghost
17  E   Ghost   -39.1658809 Ghost
18  F   Ghost   -40.7719511 Ghost
19  G   Ghost   -42.3563566 Ghost
20  H   Ghost   -43.9276406 Ghost
21  I   Ghost   -44.1853049 Ghost
22  J   Ghost   -44.4301904 Ghost
23  K   Ghost   -18.3848686 Ghost
24  L   Ghost   0   Ghost
```

and creates a stacked bar chart:

```
ggplot(data=myData, aes(x=Var1, y=value, fill=Var3, order=-as.numeric(Var2))) + geom_bar(stat="identity")+
    theme_bw() + theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
    labs(x="", y="") + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels=format_si()) +
    ggtitle("myData") + 
    guides(fill=FALSE) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

My problem is that, prior to reinstalling ggplot2, the green bars came out on top (between the x-axis and the purple bars).  I assume the new treatment has to do with the warning I referenced above (although I was getting that message before too).  Is there a way to tell ggplot2 how to handle negative values since all the output is negative?  Is there a way to put the green bars on the x-axis explicitly?  I tried to mess with the order operator in the call to ggplot2 but couldn't get it to work.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: The order aesthetic is gone, and when stat is "identity" the bars are ordered as they appear in the data, so you have to reorder the actual rows to change the bar segment order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As joran points out in his comment, the `order` aesthetic is no longer supported in ggplot2 >= 2.0.0. Also, the order of the stacked bars is no longer determined by the order of the factor levels. What you have to do instead is to order the rows of the data the way that you want your bars to be ordered.

In your case, this is relatively easy because you can just order alphabetically:

```
myData <- dplyr::arrange(myData, Var3, Var1)
```

However, in general, alphabetic order might not be what you want. But you could use ordered factors instead. These allow you to have a customized order:

```
myData$Var3 <- ordered(myData$Var3, levels = c("Ghost", "Total"))
myData <- dplyr::arrange(myData, Var3, Var1)
head(myData)
##   Var1  Var2     value  Var3
## 1    A Ghost   0.00000 Ghost
## 2    B Ghost -20.36820 Ghost
## 3    C Ghost -28.23695 Ghost
## 4    D Ghost -33.78522 Ghost
## 5    E Ghost -39.16588 Ghost
## 6    F Ghost -40.77195 Ghost
```

As you can see, the rows with `"Ghost"` in `Var3` come first now.

Now the plot has the bars ordered the way you asked for:

```
ggplot(data=myData, aes(x=Var1, y=value, fill=Var3)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

The warning message does not go away and the ordering of the bar seems not to have a connection with it. It goes away, if you have only positive values in your data: try plotting as above, but with `y=-value`. So it seems that the warning appears, if you plot bars with negative length. But I couldn't say that I understand, why this is the case.

Comment: The warning when stacking bar charts with negative values has always (at least, as far as I can remember) been present. I think it refers to the idea that if you have some bars with negative values, and some without, it is difficult to tell what the user wanted: should the bars with no negative values start at zero, or at the minimum negative value? Personally, I probably would have picked a behavior and removed the warning, but that's just me.

Comment: @joran Thanks for yiur insights!

Answer (score 0):

```
myData$Var2 <- factor(myData$Var2, levels = rev(levels(myData$Var2)))
```

This should help. Also, you should change the `as.numeric()` in the order = in ggplot.

Comment: This only makes sense, if `myData$Var2` is already a factor (which it might be, we just don't know). It will not help the OP for two reasons: 1) he uses `Var3`, not `Var2` in the plot; 2) as pointed out by joran, the order of the bars is determined by row order in the data and not the order of the factor levels. Therefore, this will not change the order of the bars.

Comment: Agreed that the answer is rushed and inaccurate, thanks for pointing out!